# Pulling an image from Drive using Google Drive API in node.js

Tags: node.js, image, google-api

I am attempting to pull a selected image from a google drive folder, run it through a resizing function, and then push the new image to an external device. In order to test the resizing and pushing functions, I have run many tests to ensure that those have no issues. Yet every time I run the code while attempting to pull the image directly out of my drive folder, the image is lost.

Skipping what I have around the program, I think that I can isolate the problem to one of 2 lines below.

//Pulling the image

```
    image = `https://drive.google.com/file/d/${ChoosenFileID}`;
```

//Pushing the image

```
    await http.get(`http://${config.deviceIP}/setparm?password=1234&background_image=${image}`);
```

*Note image is declared as a var

Looking online I have seen that google changed the way the API deals with images, yet cannot find the proper method to pull/push images for the recent update and the older ways are no longer working.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `Yet every time I run the code while attempting to pull the image directly out of my drive folder, the image is lost.` and ``image = `https://drive.google.com/file/d/${ChoosenFileID}`;`` of `//Pulling the image`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: I found my issue, I was parsing my data twice after the call. It scrambled the data so when I tried to send it out I got really fancy gibberish. I cleaned up my fetch function and solved the issue. Thanks for the response.